# SAP Netweaver Gateway adapter - client id max 3 characters

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server, mobilefirst-adapters

Currently I'm testing the SAP Netweaver GateWay Adapter of version 6.3. It contains a lot more capabilities to interact with SAP.

When connecting to the development environment of SAP, I have to use client-id 1000. Apparently only 3 characters of my client-id are interpreted by the MobileFirst server.

E.g.

1// connecting to sap with client-id 1000 - returns with the following response: 
"set-cookie": "sap-usercontext=sap-client=100; path=/",

2// connecting to sap with client-id 2912 - returns with the following response:
"set-cookie": "sap-usercontext=sap-client=291; path=/"

Anyone facing the same problem?

Br.

Wim

Comment: Development team was pinged; we'll get back to you in this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the development team:

> We are not aware of any three character limit in the  code, however
>   passing the client ID won't work regardless as it is not being sent to
>   the server at all due to a defect.

You should open a PMR in order to receive the fix for APAR PI31148.
There is no workaround.